# C# Vector3 Rotation with Quaternion / Matrix4x4

Tags: c#, rotation, quaternions

I've got a sensor that delivers object data in a coordinate system according to [ISO 8855-2011](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axes_conventions#/media/File:RPY_angles_of_cars.png).
My sensor is positioned at [0, 0, 0] but can be "misaligned". Therefore I want to compensate for roll, pitch and yaw.

In my App I perform the necessary rotations with the System.Numerics Lib and more specifically with a vector3 as the data point ([x, y, z]) and tried either a Matrix4x4 or a Quaternion as the rotation matrix.

Without having evaluated this final result a rotation in three steps seems to work quite well (at first glance looks like to be expected in my visualization). To perform the rotation I start by specifying three Quaternions for each axis and perform the rotation one after the other.

```
Vector3 vecMeas = new Vector3(x, y, z);
Quaternion rotRoll = Quaternion.CreateFromAxisAngle(new Vector3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), rollAngle);
Quaternion rotPitch = Quaternion.CreateFromAxisAngle(new Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), pitchAngle);
Quaternion rotYaw = Quaternion.CreateFromAxisAngle(new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), yawAngle);


var vecRolled = Vector3.Transform(vecMeas, rotRoll);
var vecPitched = Vector3.Transform(vecRolled, rotPitch);
var vecResult = Vector3.Transform(vecPitched, rotYaw);
```

While this seems to work, it looks clumsy to me as the class Matrix4x4 and Quaternion offers a method called "CreateFromYawPitchRoll". I tried every combination of inputs for this method (if I remember correctly 6 combinations for the order of pitch, roll, yaw combined with 48 combinations of inputs for the order and sign of [x, y, z]), but was not able to produce the same as my rotation in 3 steps.

Example (one of ~288 combinations):

```
Vector3 vecMeas = new Vector3(x, y, z);
Quaternion rot = Quaternion.CreateFromYawPitchRoll(pitch, roll, yaw);
var vecResult = Vector3.Transform(vecMeas, rot);
```

The above shown "one step" solutions always looks off.

Unfortunately I was not able to find a a lot of information about the handedness (or the absence thereof) of the expected inputs for Matrix4x4 / Quaternion or the order in which the rotation of "CreateFromYawPitchRoll" is being performed. Do you have any idea, how I could refactor my code to be more elegant (aka maybe a one step solution) or how to properly use CreateFromYawPitchRoll? A multiplication of the rotation elements did not deliver the expected results (rotRoll * rotPitch * rotYaw).

Thanks in advance!

Update:
Sorry, I think I figured it out.
In my case I have to do the following:

```
Quaternion rot = Quaternion.CreateFromYawPitchRoll(yawAngle, pitchAngle, rollAngle);
var vecRot = Vector3.Transform(new Vector3(Y, Z, X), rot);
```

The result will be:

```
var vecRes = new Vector3(vecRot.Z, vecRot.X, vecRot.Y);
```

Answer (score 0):

the updated answer works well

```
Quaternion rot = Quaternion.CreateFromYawPitchRoll(yawAngle, pitchAngle, rollAngle);
var vecRot = Vector3.Transform(new Vector3(Y, Z, X), rot);
```